# Select rows to average into information of another row manually in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am performing some manual data cleaning and I want to expedite matters. I have a dataframe such as the following:

```
ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 Group Categorical_1 Categorical_2 Categorical_3
A   1 2  2  2  2  B21       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
B   2 3  5  8  3  B24       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
C   3 4  6  1  1  A28       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
D   4 1  5  7  8  A61       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
E   5 2  8  3  2  A62       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
F   6 3  9  5  9  C91       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
G   7 4  1  4  6  D90       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
```

Suppose I want to create new rows for IDs H and I. H's group would be B22. I want all of its variables to be averages of the variables for other units in groups starting with B2. ID I, should be group A64, and its variables should be an average of all units in groups starting starting with A6. The categorical variables are text that I do not want copied or averaged to the new rows IDs. The output would therefore look like the following:

```
ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 Group Categorical_1 Categorical_2 Categorical_3
A   1 2  2  2  2  B21       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
B   2 3  5  8  3  B24       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
C   3 4  6  1  1  A28       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
D   4 1  5  7  8  A61       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
E   5 2  8  3  2  A62       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
F   6 3  9  5  9  C91       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
G   7 4  1  4  6  D90       [Text]      [Text]        [Text]
H   1.5 2.5 3.5 5 2.5 B22       
I   4.5 1.5 6.5 5 5 A64
```

I need to repeat this manually for many different observations with different IDs, so how can I set up the code to be readily adaptable as I repeat this process? Preferably it would be great to do this in `dplyr` but any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Those two will be left as is and not factor into the creation of new rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a little function, and call that function when you want a new row:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(id,grp,grp_pattern,data,cols="^V") {
  m = data %>% filter(grepl(grp_pattern,Group)) %>% summarize(across(matches(cols), mean))
  bind_rows(data, bind_cols(tibble(ID=id, Group=grp), m))
}

df = f("H", "B22", "^B2", df)
df = f("I", "A64", "^A6", df)
df = f("W", "IPG2", "^IPG",df)
```

Output:

```
   ID  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 Group Categorical_1 Categorical_2 Categorical_3
1   A 1.0 2.0 2.0   2 2.0   B21        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
2   B 2.0 3.0 5.0   8 3.0   B24        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
3   C 3.0 4.0 6.0   1 1.0   A28        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
4   D 4.0 1.0 5.0   7 8.0   A61        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
5   E 5.0 2.0 8.0   3 2.0   A62        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
6   F 6.0 3.0 9.0   5 9.0   C91        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
7   G 7.0 4.0 1.0   4 6.0   D90        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
8   H 1.5 2.5 3.5   5 2.5   B22          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
9   I 4.5 1.5 6.5   5 5.0   A64          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
10  W NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  IPG2          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
```

```
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), V1 = 1:7, 
    V2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), V3 = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    8L, 9L, 1L), V4 = c(2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L), V5 = c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 6L), Group = c("B21", "B24", "A28", "A61", 
    "A62", "C91", "D90"), Categorical_1 = c("[Text]", "[Text]", 
    "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]"), Categorical_2 = c("[Text]", 
    "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]"
    ), Categorical_3 = c("[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", 
    "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I've updated the solution to allow for different types of patterns. The function `f()` now takes a `grp_pattern` param which should be passed the regex pattern for matching.

Comment: Thank you for updating this. Unfortunately, I get the following error: ```Error in `vec_rbind()`:
! Can't combine `..1$ID` <double> and `..2$ID` <character>.
Backtrace:
 1. global f("W", "IPG2", "^IPG", df)
 2. dplyr::bind_rows(...)
 3. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .ID)```

Comment: hmm, do you have example input data on which it fails, because it doesn't fail on the data you currently provide

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake with the dataset on my end. Your solution works absolutely perfectly. And it's so flexible for the repeated edits I must make, which is ideal. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

An option is to `filter` the rows where Group starts with 'A6' or 'B2', then grouped by the `substring` of 'Group', get the `mean` of `numeric` columns and bind with the original data

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1  %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Group, "^(A6|B2|IPG2)")) %>% 
  group_by(Group = str_replace(Group, "^([A-Z]+\\d)\\d+", "\\1")) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  mutate(ID = c("H", "I"), .before = 1) %>%
  mutate(Group = str_c(Group, c("4", "2"))) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1, .)
```

-output

```
 ID  V1  V2  V3 V4  V5 Group Categorical_1 Categorical_2 Categorical_3
1  A 1.0 2.0 2.0  2 2.0   B21        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
2  B 2.0 3.0 5.0  8 3.0   B24        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
3  C 3.0 4.0 6.0  1 1.0   A28        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
4  D 4.0 1.0 5.0  7 8.0   A61        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
5  E 5.0 2.0 8.0  3 2.0   A62        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
6  F 6.0 3.0 9.0  5 9.0   C91        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
7  G 7.0 4.0 1.0  4 6.0   D90        [Text]        [Text]        [Text]
8  H 4.5 1.5 6.5  5 5.0   A64          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
9  I 1.5 2.5 3.5  5 2.5   B22          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), V1 = 1:7, 
    V2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), V3 = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    8L, 9L, 1L), V4 = c(2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L), V5 = c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 6L), Group = c("B21", "B24", "A28", "A61", 
    "A62", "C91", "D90"), Categorical_1 = c("[Text]", "[Text]", 
    "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]"), 
Categorical_2 = c("[Text]", 
    "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]"
    ), Categorical_3 = c("[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]", 
    "[Text]", "[Text]", "[Text]")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is almost perfect. I have one problem though: I adopted this for another row, where the row I want to create is ID = W and its group is IPG2. I therefore want it to take average the observations of rows in groups starting with IPG. Following this approach, it created rows for new groups IPG11, IPG31, IPG41, and IPG51 instead. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to simplify it. Sorry!

Comment: @flâneur I updated but you may have to make some adjustment in the last steps

Comment: Thank you! Unfortuantely, this still reproduces the multiple IPG(X) variables without creating the new IPG2 as the average of them. I suspect it is problem something to do with the regex code in the str_detect

Comment: @flâneur Can you update your post with the `dput` of a small reproducible example that shows the issue so that it can be checked.  Please note that I did mention to modify the last steps of code i.e. `mutate(Group = str_c(Group, c("4", "2")))` assumes there are only two Groups, but with `IPG, it wil e 3 groups, and it can be `mutate(Group = str_c(Group, c("4", "2", "2")))`